# extracting numbers in list to dict of lists

Tags: list, dictionary, numbers, iteration

I have a dict of lists that looks similarly to this:

```
'H82746': ['Hsa.1070', 'H82746', 'U1', 'SMALL', 'NUCLEAR', 'RIBONUCLEOPROTEIN', 'C', ';.', '1.75', '1.46', '1.75', '1.69', '1.30', '1.11', '1.42', '1.11', '1.92', '0.99', '0.65', '1.69', '1.39', '1.29', '1.55', '2.00', '1.16', '0.70', '1.48', '0.78', '1.52', '1.28', '1.50', '0.79', '1.31', '1.56', '1.33', '1.66', '1.67', '1.34', '1.48', '0.38', '0.76', '1.27', '1.66', '1.12', '1.40', '1.23', '1.66', '1.58', '2.33', '1.25', '0.90', '0.63', '0.58', '0.97', '0.79', '0.90', '1.25', '1.52', '1.78', '1.56', '1.66', '1.39', '1.42', '1.07', '1.63', '2.00', '2.06', '1.37', '1.38', '1.33']
```

I want to extract all of the numbers (just the number entries like '1.66' and '1.42', not the number-letter-combos like 'H82746' or 'Hsa.1070'), so I can add them to the key in the dict of lists. 
I have tried iterating over number and i, but I have not succeeded in extracting only the numbers. do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: What language are you using? Please provide more details.

Comment: it is in python.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve, but from what I understood you can do the following:

```
$ echo "<your_string>" | grep -o "'[0-9\.]*'" > extracted_numbers.txt
```

which will write number to the **extracted_numbers.txt** file in following format:

```
'1.75'
'1.46'
'1.75'
...
```

Comment: I work in python and I want to remove any non-number entry in the list to the keys.